# How to set breakpoint in Delve with an init-command

Tags: go, debugging, delve

In GDB, there is a flag `--init-command` which I can define a command like `b dbConnection` and it will be applied automatically after running the project. It sets the breakpoint on the `dbConnection` function.

I was looking for the same in Delve but I couldn't find it.
The whole idea is instead of running dlv command and then telling where is my function and set the breakpoint there, I wanna give the function name before running dlv as init command like `break pkg/db/connection.go:dbConnection`. I can run fzf command to find the file easily and then I'll pass it to the dlv init command to set the breakpoint there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer https://github.com/go-delve/delve/discussions/3189

The flag is `--init`. For example:

```bash
dlv debug --init <(echo b main.main)
```